# Positioning UIControls in UITableViewCells in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder

So I have a `UITableView` in a `.xib` file. That's all that's in it.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I use a custom `UITableViewCell`.  The `UITableViewCell` width in IB is `320`.

I dropped in a `UISegmentedControl` and centered it per the blue guide lines.  When I present the table in a popover, the `UISegmentedControl` in the `UITableViewCell` is not centered.  It's like the `UITableViewCell` gets cut off.  I included a picture.

Is there something that I am forgetting in the sizes of things?  I have another 4 segmented control where although the segmented control shows in the `UITableViewCell`, it is cut off.  My `contenstSizeForPopover` is set to `320` for the width also.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the cell into a group table view, the cell makes its content area 20 points narrower to allow for table border/background area.  That's why your controls are getting cut off.

You can probably just set your controls to have flexible width:

[image: autosizing with flexible width]

but you'll have to keep the resizing in mind when you design your cell layout.